# WinForm App running a console - Disabling minimize/maximize/close buttons on console issue

Tags: c#, winforms, winforms-interop

I am writing a windows forms app that can launch a console for debugging. I want to disable the close button of the console so that the windows forms app cannot be shut down through the close button of the console. I have built the test code skeleton and it works. The code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace bsa_working
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static bool console_on = false;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ViewConsole.Checked)
            {
                Win32.AllocConsole();
                ConsoleProperties.ConsoleMain();

                // Set console flag to true
                console_on = true;  // will be used later
            }
            else
                Win32.FreeConsole();
        }
    }

    public class Win32
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern Boolean AllocConsole();
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern Boolean FreeConsole();
    }

    public class ConsoleProperties
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool EnableMenuItem(IntPtr hMenu, uint uIDEnableItem, uint uEnable);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr RemoveMenu(IntPtr hMenu, uint nPosition, uint wFlags);

        internal const uint SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;
        internal const uint MF_GRAYED = 0x00000001;
        internal const uint MF_BYCOMMAND = 0x00000000;

        public static void ConsoleMain()
        {
            IntPtr hMenu = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;
            IntPtr hSystemMenu = GetSystemMenu(hMenu, false);

            EnableMenuItem(hSystemMenu, SC_CLOSE, MF_GRAYED);
            RemoveMenu(hSystemMenu, SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND);

            // Set console title
            Console.Title = "Test Console";

            // Set console surface foreground and background color
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

The code works fine EXCEPT:

1. When the code is compiled and run the first time, the X on the console is NOT grayed out but it is grayed out on the Windows Forms app. However, when the code is closed down and run again, the code works as it should; that is, the X on the console is grayed out and the Windows Forms app is as it should be. Any ideas why and how this can be fixed?
2. Sometimes the console comes up behind the win form. Any way to force the console to always come on top?

As an aside, is there any way the console can be pinned to a specific spot on the WinForm? app? I can set its size so if I could pin it in a specific spot I could create a spot for it on the form.

Comment: Why dont you simply have a windows forms within you application, for example another form or control witth inside a text box with multiline enabled then you redirect standard output of the console to this control without all this magic you are trying to do?

Comment: Because the console is primarily for debugging and I don't necessarily want to see it all the time.

Comment: @Zeos6: I do the same thing in some of my apps.  I really like how it works.  Instead of calling `Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle` (which can result in a race between the form and the console window), after the call to AllocConsole() get the console window handle by calling `GetConsoleWindow()`

Comment: I think GetConsoleWindow() only works for XP and I want it to work even in non XP OS environment.

Comment: I can't repro on my system (Win7 64bit). That does support Boo's advice about a race condition. Though I don't get why the console becomes the main window for the process at all.

Comment: @Zeos6 - boo's answer works on win7x64

Comment: I spent way too much time on this a few years back. The only way I found to make it work reliably (i.e. remove the X and the Close item from the system menu, and grey out the X) was to call `DeleteMenu`. See http://blog.mischel.com/2008/07/14/going-too-far-back/ for a little more detail and caveats.

Comment: As far as making sure that the console window always ends up on top, I think my solution was to handle the Form's `Shown` event and then call `SetForegroundWindow` with the console's window handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make that work you need to change `IntPtr hMenu = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;` to use the Window Handle of the Console Window instead (which you can obtain by calling [`GetConsoleWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

To make it display on top you could use for example [`SetForegroundWindow` with the Console Window Handle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

About the pinning I am really not sure whether this is even possible.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I agree re the race condition, and I also think that pinning is probably a no go. I just thought to ask in case I was missing something. My only objection ito GetConsoleWindow() is that it only works for Win 2000 and XP. If you try a work around (which exists) then there are issues if you have multiple comsoles as the workaround only finds the nearestone in the z order. I ws hoping to avoid using GetConsoleWindow().

Comment: @Zeos6 there is only ever at maximum ONE Console associated with your application (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) so that won't be a problem... AND `GetConsoleWindow` works for later Windows versions too! Please don't forget to upvote/mark as accepted any answer that was of help (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Thanks Yahia. I will mark the answer. I agree with you re only one console with alloc. I guess my confusion is if I have multiple apps and each app creates a console then which console will I get? As I understand it, you will get the nearest console in z order, not necessarily the one linked to the app you want. Also, thanks re the SetForeGroundWindow. In any case, I may need to go with GetConsoleWindow() although I would prefer not to.

Comment: @Zeos6 You will absolutely not get "the nearest" but according to MS exactly the Console associated with your app (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)... this API call only takes into account the process context NOT any screen coordinates.